# I got error while getting all the list of members from guild

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I used `async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):` to get all the members from the chosen guild and I already tried to set the bot's permission to administrator and top of everyone, but still, there is the same problem. I want to get all the lists of members' IDs from a single guild.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
  File "Stock.py", line 85, in on_message
  File "discord\iterators.py", line 86, in __anext__
  File "discord\iterators.py", line 605, in next
  File "discord\iterators.py", line 627, in fill_members
  File "discord\http.py", line 241, in request
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

Comment: you need to enable members intents on discord developer portal & through the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have the `guild` object you can get all member `id` in the specific guild by this code

```
member_id_list = [ member.id for member in guild.members ]
```

I used [guild.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members) to get all member object in the guild and iterate through it and saved every member id in `member_id_list` list. read document for more info!

**NOTE:** make sure that you enabled `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` in your discord developer portal! and add this in your code!

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&',intents = intents)
```

because without that your bot can't fetch all members in the guild!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your code, you can try this instead:

```
member_ids = []
for member in guild.members:
    member_ids.append(member.id)
```

Comment: If you are aware of the changes to discord you will know that you must supply intents to use these features. `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden` should tell you the request was not allowed to happen therefore it's not a code issue